# Qt XML serialization adds extra characters

Tags: c++, xml, qt, serialization, newline

I have a method serializing a free text input into an XML node using Qt. This text may contain newline characters. The problem is that when I serialize this text and deserialize it again, a few extra newline characters are getting inserted in the output stream.

This is my serialization method:

```
QDomElement textElement = doc.createElement("Sql");
QDomText cdata = doc.createTextNode(m_sql);
textElement.appendChild(cdata);
```

This is the text I want to serialize:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(a INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
     return 1;
END
```

This is what I get in the serialized file:

> `<Sql>CREATE FUNCTION func(a INT) RETURNS INT&#xd;&#xd;`
>
> `BEGIN&#xd;&#xd;`
>
> ```
>    return 1;&#xd;&#xd;
> ```
>
> `END&#xd;&#xd;</Sql>`

(I know this looks horrible, but there are NEWLINEs after `&#xd;&#xd;` and this editor did not make it possible to show them as they are there that's why it seems there is an empty line between the lines.)

and this is what I get after desrializing:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(a INT) RETURNS INT


BEGIN


    return 1;


END
```

so as you can see the newlines are doubled... any clue how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `QIODevice::Text` flag when open file for reading.
From QFile documentation:

> The `QIODevice::Text` flag passed to `open()` tells Qt to convert
>   Windows-style line terminators ("`\r\n`") into C++-style terminators
>   ("`\n`"). By default, QFile assumes binary, i.e. it doesn't perform
>   any conversion on the bytes stored in the file.